# CSS Center Float

Tags: css, html, css-float

Just a quickie, i am probably being silly here but anyway:

I have a navigation that is centrally positioned with margins, this has a list of links, the problem i am having is that because all of my `<li>` classes are given the css: `float:left` they align on the left.

E.G:

[image: nav example]

What i would like to know is if there is any way to center these?

Thanks

CSS:

```
section#nav {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
nav {
    max-width: 700px;
    height: 45px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
    padding:12px 15px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav ul li {
    font-size:14px; 
    float:left;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin:0 10px;  
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important;
}

nav ul li a.nav-path-selected {
    border-bottom:1px #ffffff solid;
}

nav ul li a.nav-path-selected {
    border-bottom:1px #ffffff solid;
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#CCCCCC !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="nav">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-selected nav-path-selected">
        <a class="nav-selected nav-path-selected" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/opportunities/">Opportunities</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/inspiration/">Inspiration</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/members/">Members</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I have used a combination of your answers to build the solution:

```
nav ul {
    padding:12px 15px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav ul li {
    font-size:14px; 
    display:inline-block;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can something like this

```
ul{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

ul>li{
    display:inline;
}
```

Using display:inline instead display:inline-block may don't affect in appearance, but allow display correctly on IE 7

check here [jsfiddle.net/kmcYE/2](http://jsfiddle.net/kmcYE/2)

Answer (score 0):

Put your < ul > element inside a < div > and then size and center the div on the page. As long as you set the div to an explicit width value (such as the width of your menu items) and then set the right and left margins of the div to auto, it will auto center.

Comment: Remember to use clear:left or clear:both to <ul> calculate its width correctly. Or set manualy with CSS

Answer (score 0):

The only adjustment needed if on your `li` css:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97vZg/) Example.

**ADD**

```
display:inline-block;
```

**REMOVE**

```
float:left;
```

Comment: display:inline-block can cause issues in IE7

Comment: @JoãoMosmann Have you looked at the CSS used? IE7 isn't an issue, otherwise this menu will never work as is :)

Comment: My comment is just for knowledge :)

But just because he is using CSS3 and HTML5 tag don't means that he dont pay attention to IE7 :P He can be using HTML5shiv

Comment: @Downvoter: The reason would be nice! One can't understand what's wrong if no one points it out.

Answer (score 0):

Give `nav ul` a `display: inline-block;` property. This will shrink the list to the width of its contents and center it horizontally in its containing element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VMqUe/